# how override spring framework beans?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, authorization

I want to customize some of the codes of OAuth authorization server provided by spring security. the code responsible for generating /oauth/authorize is a bean named AuthorizationEndpoint. in AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration class the following code creates a bean of AuthorizationEndpoint class:

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint() throws Exception {
    AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint = new AuthorizationEndpoint();
    FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping mapping = getEndpointsConfigurer().getFrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping();
    authorizationEndpoint.setUserApprovalPage(extractPath(mapping, "/oauth/confirm_access"));
    authorizationEndpoint.setProviderExceptionHandler(exceptionTranslator());
    authorizationEndpoint.setErrorPage(extractPath(mapping, "/oauth/error"));
    authorizationEndpoint.setTokenGranter(tokenGranter());
    authorizationEndpoint.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
    authorizationEndpoint.setAuthorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices());
    authorizationEndpoint.setOAuth2RequestFactory(oauth2RequestFactory());
    authorizationEndpoint.setOAuth2RequestValidator(oauth2RequestValidator());
    authorizationEndpoint.setUserApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler());
    return authorizationEndpoint;
}
```

I want to override it by a new custom bean. I have created a class which extends AuthorizationEndpoint. for now I have pasted the same code inside this new class.

```
public class AuthorizationEndpointCustom extends AuthorizationEndpoint {
```

creating the bean:

```
    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration asec;


    @Bean
//  @Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Primary
    public AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint () {

        AuthorizationEndpointCustom authorizationEndpoint = new AuthorizationEndpointCustom();
        FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping mapping = asec.getEndpointsConfigurer().getFrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping();
        authorizationEndpoint.setUserApprovalPage(extractPath(mapping, "/oauth/confirm_access"));
        authorizationEndpoint.setProviderExceptionHandler(asec.getEndpointsConfigurer().getExceptionTranslator());
        authorizationEndpoint.setErrorPage(extractPath(mapping, "/oauth/error"));
        authorizationEndpoint.setTokenGranter(asec.getEndpointsConfigurer().getTokenGranter());
        authorizationEndpoint.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        authorizationEndpoint.setAuthorizationCodeServices(asec.getEndpointsConfigurer().getAuthorizationCodeServices());
        authorizationEndpoint.setOAuth2RequestFactory(asec.getEndpointsConfigurer().getOAuth2RequestFactory());
        authorizationEndpoint.setOAuth2RequestValidator(asec.getEndpointsConfigurer().getOAuth2RequestValidator());
        authorizationEndpoint.setUserApprovalHandler(asec.getEndpointsConfigurer().getUserApprovalHandler());

        return authorizationEndpoint;
    }

    private String extractPath(FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping mapping, String page) {
        String path = mapping.getPath(page);
        if (path.contains(":")) {
            return path;
        }
        return "forward:" + path;
    }
```

when I try to create a bean of this new class I encounter the following error:

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> The bean 'authorizationEndpoint', defined in
>   org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration,
>   could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been
>   defined in class path resource
>   [com/example/demo/AuthorizationServerConfig.class] and overriding is
>   disabled.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
>   spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

the error goes away by adding the suggested config to application.properties. but the new bean does not replace the framework bean. in another part of my code I accessed the AuthorizationEndpoint from applicationContext. I called the .getClass() of this object and it is the same bean from the framework:

> "org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint"

how can I force spring to use my bean?

Comment: I am not sure if `.getClass()` is the best way to test. The error before indicated you are replacing the bean. Anyway, you can exclude the Autoconfiguration class, where you found the spring code with `@SpringBootApplication(exclude=<Configurationclass>.class) ` but this means you have to implement this whole configuration class yourself.

Comment: hi @PeMa. thanks for your advice. this is certainly a way to consider. but I found out there is a simple way to override framework endpoints.

Comment: in the matter of beans being overridden, I think actually my own bean is overridden by framework bean. not vise versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I red an article about overriding beans and it seems so messy and unpredictable. [read here](https://brudenko.com/spring-bean-override)
it's best to avoid doing so. The solution to disable framework bean lies in excluding the configuration class which creates it. but this means we have to implement the hole thing ourselves.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=<AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration>.class)
```

but the solution to overriding the framework endpoints is much easier.all we have to do is create a controller with mapping for /oauth/authorize

> Customizing the UI Most of the Authorization Server endpoints are used
>   primarily by machines, but there are a couple of resource that need a
>   UI and those are the GET for /oauth/confirm_access and the HTML
>   response from /oauth/error. They are provided using whitelabel
>   implementations in the framework, so most real-world instances of the
>   Authorization Server will want to provide their own so they can
>   control the styling and content. All you need to do is provide a
>   Spring MVC controller with @RequestMappings for those endpoints, and
>   the framework defaults will take a lower priority in the dispatcher.
>   In the /oauth/confirm_access endpoint you can expect an
>   AuthorizationRequest bound to the session carrying all the data needed
>   to seek approval from the user (the default implementation is
>   WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint so look there for a starting point to
>   copy). You can grab all the data from that request and render it
>   however you like, and then all the user needs to do is POST back to
>   /oauth/authorize with information about approving or denying the
>   grant. The request parameters are passed directly to a
>   UserApprovalHandler in the AuthorizationEndpoint so you can interpret
>   the data more or less as you please. The default UserApprovalHandler
>   depends on whether or not you have supplied an ApprovalStore in your
>   AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer (in which case it is an
>   ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler) or not (in which case it is a
>   TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler). The standard approval handlers accept
>   the following:

read more [here](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).

there is another question related to this subject: [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249106/spring-customizing-the-authorizationendpoint-oauth2/60293833#60293833)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Configuration` class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationEndpoint authorizationEndpoint() {
        if(...) return new AuthorizationEndpoint();
        else return new AuthorizationEndpointCustom();
    }
}
```

Comment: check also https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350865/spring-choose-bean-implementation-at-runtime

Comment: I think the bean overriding error would not occur if the OP forgot the `@Configuration`, and conditional bean configuration can (as far as I know) only be applied to the configuration class, which is not possible with an imported starter. But actually the starter itself should do so.

Comment: as @PeMa said I have place the code inside a configuration class. I red something about overriding beans and it seems so messy and unpredictable